# binding keypress not working - jquery tools overlay

Tags: overlay, jquery, jquery-tools

I can't bind keypress for a div that I applied overlay to.
Bellow is the code.

```
<div> 
    Content  <a href="#" id="load">Load overlay</a>
</div>

<div id="overlayDiv" class="overlay">
    <div id="someInnerDiv">
         Text 

    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript> 
    function LoadOverlay()
    {
        $('#overlayDiv').overlay();
        $('#someInnerDiv').keypress(function() { alert (' key was pressed' ); });
        $('#someInnerDiv').focus();
    }
    $("#load").click(LoadOverlay);​
</script>
```

Alert is not showing up. 
Here is the code on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JEmgg/4/

I am guessing that it's the overlay that catches the event, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: what you are trying to do ? hit `esc` to close the overlay ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you can't insert text without a textarea, an input type text or other input element.
try this code and it works:
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JEmgg/6/)

```
<div id="overlayDiv" class="overlay">
    <div id="someInnerDiv">
         Text
        <input type="text" name="test" id="test"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: unless you use at the `$(document)`, then keypress will work to, but dont think this is the case.

Comment: No I think this isn't the case because he want catch inside the div the keypress

Answer (score 3):

keypress event works if you replace that div with some textarea or input type='text' so when you type, the keypress event occurs and alert will work.

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/JEmgg/5/

Replace :

```
  <div id="someInnerDiv" ></div>
```

with

```
 <input type="text" id="someInnerDiv" />
```